# Osmosis vs protein-binding in preserving foods through salting

Tags: protein-binding, osmosis, food-chemistry

I had assumed that the preservative function of covering foods with NaCl or brine was due to osmosis killing the microorganisms on the food by dehydration.  However, I am now wondering to what extent denaturing of bacterial protein through interaction with salt ions could be responsible for killing the microorganisms.  And what evidence suggests a dominant role for one or the other mechanism.  I hope someone can clarify this matter for me.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to killing microorganisms, the salt may provide a better environment for some 'beneficial' organisms, and a less beneficial environment for other 'problem' organisms. For instance, in production of kimchi and sauerkraut, salt encourages lactofermentation to the detriment of more harmful bacteria and fungi.

Comment: This is interesting, and implies that the relative importance of osmosis vs protein-binding when preserving food with salt depends on the type of microorganism targeted.  But I still wonder about the importance of osmosis in food preservation, whether or not lactofermentation is involved.  In the latter case, are harmful microorganisms killed by dehydration?